# How to strip the following html tags from user input in PHP?

Tags: php

I don't want to use htmlentities() because I just want to strip 3 kinds of tags and allow all others. These are the ones to be stripped:

```
- <a hrefs...
- <scripts...
- <img src...
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You sure you want to allow _all_ others?  What's your actual reason for wanting to remove these ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = strip_tags($str, '<a><script><img>');
```

However, if this is for security, **this is not enough**. Use a HTML parser and a whitelist of allowed tags and attributes.

Otherwise I may enter `<button onclick="alert('xss')">hello!</button>`, for example.

Comment: I would second the "this is not enough" comment since if you allow people to post html they can add a "onmouseover" attribute to any tag.  For example, even if you only allowed the `<strong>` tag I can do `<strong style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute" onmouseover="alert('xss');">...</strong>` and this will execute anytime the mouse is moved over the page.

Comment: @JustJohn Just another reason to use a whitelist and parser. I chose the obvious HTML sample to point it out :P

Comment: indeed. Or ditch html altogether and use something like markdown or bbcode run through a well developed library with XSS protection.

Answer (score 1):

Check out php's [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/strip_tags).  The optional parameter allows you to select allowable tags, which I know is the opposite of what you want to, but is the better way to go.

The other option is to use regular expressions to remove those offending tags.